# expected 2 arguments, but got 1 in Angular8

Tags: angular

I use static concepts but why I am getting this type of error Expected 2 arguments but got 1. Statically I declare all my requirements in my component.html file but why am getting this type of error?

Below I describe my codes I got error exact this point:

```
<td>
  <button (click)="deleteProduct(prodlist.id)" class="btn btn-warning">DeleteProduct</button>
```

product.component.html

```
<h1><b>Product Lists</b></h1>
    <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf='message'>{{message}}</div>
    <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>OrderDate</th>
                <th>DelicerDate</th>
                <th>Is Xomplete</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- this *ngFor is forEach loop in java
            where you declare for( int prod : products){} -->
            <tr *ngFor="let prodlist of proudLists">
            <td>{{prodlist.product}}</td>
            <td>{{prodlist.price}}</td>
            <td>{{prodlist.orderdate | date}}</td>
            <td>{{prodlist.deliverdate | date}}</td>
            <td>{{prodlist.done}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="deleteProduct(prodlist.id)" class="btn btn-warning">DeleteProduct</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductdataService } from '../service/data/productdata.service';

export class Product{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public product : String,
    public price : number,
    public orderdate : Date,
    public deliverdate : Date,
    public done : boolean
  ){

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productlist',
  templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css']
})
export class ProductlistComponent implements OnInit {
  proudLists : Product[];
  message : String;
  
  constructor(private prodataservice : ProductdataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.prodataservice.retriveAllProducts('Printer')
      .subscribe(
        response =>{
          console.log(response);
          this.proudLists=response;
        }
      )
  }
  deleteProduct(productname,id){
    console.log(`gao hand ${id}`);
    this.prodataservice.deleteProduct('Printer',id).subscribe(
      response =>{
        console.log(response);
       this.message='Dele of ${id} successFull';
      }
    )
  }

}
```

> productdata.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from 'src/app/productlist/productlist.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductdataService {

  constructor(private htp:HttpClient ) { }
  retriveAllProducts(productname){
   return this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`)
  }
  deleteProduct(productname,id){
    return this.htp.delete(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/prodct/${id}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a typo. I think you meant `deleteProduct(prodlist, id)` - a comma (",") instead of a   period (".")

Answer (score 1):

you get this error because this button:

```
<button (click)="deleteProduct(prodlist.id)" class="btn btn-warning">DeleteProduct</button>
```

should look like this:

```
<button (click)="deleteProduct('product name',prodlist.id)" class="btn btn-warning">DeleteProduct</button>
```

I looked in your deleteProduct(productname, id) in the controller and there you don't use the productname variable anywhere so just change the function in the controller to deleteProduct(id)